# Converting 12 hours to 24 hours in R

Tags: r

How do we convert a vector of 12 hour character into 24 hours? For example, lets say I have a vector

```
v = c('9AM','10AM','1PM','5PM')
```

and I'm trying to get an output of 9, 10, 13, 17 based on AM/PM and appending AM/PM.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> v = c('9AM','10AM','1PM','5PM')
>>> times = strptime(v, "%I%p")


[1] "2018-04-06 09:00:00 GMT" "2018-04-06 10:00:00 GMT" "2018-04-06 13:00:00 GMT" "2018-04-06 17:00:00 GMT"
```

If you just need the hour

```
>>> times$hour #as commented by @thelatemail

[1] 9 10 13 17
```

or

```
>>> library(lubridate)
>>> hour(times)

[1] 9 10 13 17
```

Comment: Also, `format(as.POSIXct(v, format ="%I%p"), "%H")`